# iOS message composer fields non editable

Tags: ios

Is there any way I can make Message compose Controller components non-editable if not so please let me know any alternate solution to do the same. Is there any way to navigate back to the application once the message sent through message composer?...

Comment: How you are showing message composer ?

Comment: Presenting MFMessageComposeViewController by setting their fields